# Div not containing another element when width is set in FF

Tags: jquery, html, css

Could anyone explain this behavior in Firefox?
When I click on the div, I simply set it's width to what it was. However, it no longer contains the h1, which has the same width.

html:

```
<div>
  <h1>This is a header</h1>
</div>
```

css:

```
div{
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var $div = $('div');
$div.on('click', function(){
  $('div').width($('div').width());
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLKj8/)

Comment: I've just ran your fiddle in FF, and when I click the div, the header stays within the div, but the div gets a width style added. I don't see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the width has a fraction (e.g. 216.02 pixels) which get rounded down by offsetWidth, clientWidth or jQuery width function. To get the exact value, you need to check the computed style width property.
e.g. `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('my_div'),null).width`

http://jsfiddle.net/rLKj8/1/